# How to get all the playlists of my YouTube library?

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get **all the playlists** of **my YouTube library** with **YouTube Data API**?

[image: My YouTube library]

When I try, I only get the playlists I created myself, not all the playlists added to my library.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list#try-it
2. In the **mine** dropdown, choose: `true`
3. Click on "**Execute**"
4. Allow the application in your account.
5. You'll see: It only returns the playlists you created yourself, not all the playlists added to your library.

Comment: Are you interested in all playlists of YouTube Library that are: your history, your videos to watch later, your playlists, your liked videos and your clips or just a subset of these playlists? As some are *difficult* to retrieve, please be the most precise as possible.

Comment: I understand your question and I see no way to get all playlist from the library using YouTube Data API. This is due (*imho*), the linked/saved playlists are just that - a *link* between your the given playlist and your channel. Consider post a issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:186600&s=created_time:desc).